# Strange behavior in implementations of abstract Activity

Tags: android, inheritance, event-handling, thread-safety, handler

I've come upon a rather strange problem.

I have an abstract Activity creating some threads, and handling messages using a Handler by calling an abstract handleEvent()-method.

Upon certain events one of many child activities implementing this abstract parent activity are created using intents - the normal way.

Now for the strange part: Each of these child activities implement and override the abstract activity's handleEvent()-method.

However, the handleEvent()-method in any of the child activities - except the first one - never gets called!

Can someone explain this behavior?

Trying to be more clear:

Abstract Parent receives event-> Create Activity ChildA
Abstract Parent receives event -> Create Activity ChildB
Abstract Parent receives event -> Create Activity ChildC

Parent receives event that handleEvent() should handle - but only the handleEvent-method of ChildA is called - even if ChildB or ChildC is the active Activity.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because:

> [Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that
>   thread's message queue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Which means that if handler is created in one thread the messages won't be received in the other. To overcome this problem, create the `Handler` this way:

```
Handler yourHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

This will associate the `Handler` with main (UI) thread.

Comment: The handler is in the abstract (parent) activity. The handler receives all the messages just fine. But when calling the handleEvent()-method implemented in the different child activities, only one of the handleEvent()-methods are executed - The one of the  first child. I would expect all the handleEvent()-methods in all child activities to be executed.

Comment: Then you should provide some code - it's not clear from your question how you start activities, what is your class hierarchy and so on.